# react pagination module : unexpected token at "::this._handlePageChange"

Tags: reactjs, npm, pagination

I installed paginorm from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/paginorm

A problem occurred at

```js
constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      activePage: 15
    };
    this.handlePageChange = ::this._handlePageChange;//Unexpected token (25:26)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

I have upgrade my react ("react": "^15.0.0") and react-dom ("react-dom": "^15.0.0"). What may I missing...?

Answer (score 0):

React won't understand `ES6`. So, you need to add [babel](https://babeljs.io), which will transpile you `ES6` to normal `ES5`

You need to include `babel` to your project like below

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit**

You can also use the traditional `.bind()`
Like this.

```
this.handlePageChange = this.handlePageChange.bind(this)
```

Comment: thanks, but I've already installed babel in my project.
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-jason": "^2.0.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.17.0",

Comment: As well as
"babel-core": "^6.6.0",
"babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
"babel-loader": "^6.1.0",